# Script to move files from folder to another folder using paths in text file

Tags: windows, file, move

On Windows 8, could someone please help me create a script to move some images from a particular folder to another folder?

The file path that lists the images i want to move (not all images) from the folder are listed in this file: C:\Users\Emmanuel\Desktop\test.txt

The folder in which contains some of the images I want removed appear in this folder:

C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\Images1

The folder in which I want the images to be moved to is this folder:

C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\Images2

Your help will be much appreciated

Comment: State your Operating System. If you are using Windows, XCOPY may be what you want.

Comment: i am using windows 8 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this where SourcesFile is your test.txt and DestFolder is the destination.

```
    public int Run()
    {
        if (!File.Exists(SourcesFile))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Source folder does not exist");
        }

        if (!Directory.Exists(DestFolder))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Destination folder doesn't exist");
            Console.WriteLine("Creating destination folder...");
            Directory.CreateDirectory(DestFolder);
        }

        string[] files = File.ReadAllLines(SourcesFile);
        Console.WriteLine("Moving {0} files...", files.Length);
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            string dest = Path.Combine(DestFolder, Path.GetFileName(file));
            if (File.Exists(dest))
            {
                string newFilename = string.Format("{0}_{1}{2}",
                    Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file),
                    Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"),
                    Path.GetExtension(file));

                string newDest = Path.Combine(DestFolder, newFilename);
                Console.WriteLine("File {0} already exists, copying file to {1}", file, newDest);
                File.Move(file, newDest);
                continue;
            }
            File.Move(file, dest);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```